# javascript file to handle validation on checkboxes and textbox

Tags: javascript

I had tried to get a Javascript query to handle the event generated when a radio button is clicked. Textbox will lose its disables. This code places more time.

```
function validate(element,txtValue) {
    try {
        var ele = document.getElementById(txtValue);
        alert(ele);
        if(element.value == "Any"){
        document.frmcampaign.ele.disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.frmcampaign.ele.disabled = true;
    }

    } catch(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<td>
  <input type="radio" name="<%=aName%>" id="<%=aName%>"
         value="<%=sNoPVValue%>" onclick = "validate(this,'A_pv7')">
</td>
```

Comment: you are use jquery or not?

Comment: no.. i used only javascript only..

Answer (score 0):

Try to access to the fields name array of form element by ele.name

```
function validate(element,txtValue) {
    try {
        var ele = document.getElementById(txtValue);

        if(element.value == "Any"){
            document.frmcampaign[ele.name].disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.frmcampaign[ele.name].disabled = true;
        }

    } catch(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```